# Hibernate composite annotation

Tags: hibernate, annotations, set, composite

I am new to Hibernate, and am trying to map extra columns in a join table to the parent class. I could find an example at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/components.html

```
<class name="eg.Order" .... >
....
<set name="purchasedItems" table="purchase_items" lazy="true">
<key column="order_id">
<composite-element class="eg.Purchase">
<property name="purchaseDate"/>
<property name="price"/>
<property name="quantity"/>
<many-to-one name="item" class="eg.Item"/> <!-- class attribute is optional -->
</composite-element>
</set>
</class>
```

I want the above xml example in pure annotation. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Purchase class:

```
package eg;

@javax.persistence.Embeddable
public class Purchase{

    private Date purchaseDate;
    private Double price;
    private Integer quantity;

    @javax.persistence.ManyToOne
    private Item item;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Order class:

```
package eg;

@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Order {

    @javax.persistence.ElementCollection(fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
    @javax.persistence.CollectionTable( 
         name = "purchase_items", 
         joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "order_id" ) 
    )
    java.util.Set<eg.Purchase> purchasedItems;

    // getter and setter for purchasedItems
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-ofvalues. annotations are part of the hibernate core since 3.6, IIRC, and the documentation for annotations is thus embedded in the core documentation of 3.6. For previous versions, it was documented separately (see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1821)